# how to align the butto, textfield and text in the center in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to align the button, textfield and text in the center in react?
[image]

```
    <div className="row text-center">
      <div className="text-center col-12">
        <div className="form-group text-center col-4">
          <div style={{ fontSize: "18px" }} className="field-label mb-2">
            Apply Now
          </div>
          <input
            style={{ height: "38px" }}
            className="col-12 mb-2"
            type="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={e => onEmailChange(e)}
          />
          {validator.message("email", email, "required|alpha")}
          <button
            className="btn-solid btn col-12"
            style={{ height: "45px" }}
            type="button"
            disabled={isEmailLoading}
            onClick={e => onClickApply(e)}>
            {isEmailLoading ? (
              <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} className="" />
            ) : (
              "Apply"
            )}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example (preferably on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))

Comment: So *Apply Now* should be kept in position?

Comment: the whole component, in the center

Comment: Well i'm not familiair with react. But you can just apply css, it looks like you are using bootstrap, so applying to `d-flex justify-content-center` to your third div should work. Or you can add `offset-4` to your third div.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you're using class `col-4` for your entire form. If your grid system is 12-cols (I guess it is!) your columns will be placed from left! Unless you assign offset to them(to ignore some col). If you want to put your col in center, you have to use offset! in this situation you need to pass 4 cols to center your items! If you're using bootstrap you can use `offset-4` easily!

More detail about offset in grid systems like bootstrap: [Offset Classes in Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#offset-classes)

Your div class example:

```
className="form-group text-center col-4 offset-4"
```